# How To Bake Particles Into Mesh w/ Keyframes?

Tags: animation, particles, physics

I have a particle emitter that drops a single particle, which is manipulated by forces. I've got it working perfectly, however, it is too fast and I want to slow it down.  But I don't want to slow down my entire animation, just this one falling particle.

And I don't want to mess up the dynamics because they are currently perfect otherwise, so ideally I need to bake the particle to a mesh with keyframes, so I simply scale the keyframes accordingly on the Dope Sheet.

Hitting "Apply modifier" on the Particle System just makes it disappear. I've read you can export as alembic but I don't know how to do that.  I've tried running a python script I found, but it didn't work.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Is this the same question like the one I've answered? This time just with a particle system instead of rigid bodies?

Comment: I think it is, however, your solution before doesn't work for particles, at least on my setup.  I am familiar with that solution for rigid bodies, but I couldn't get my rigid bodies to spin, as well as translate (per another question I asked, still unanswered) so I had to use a particle system.  However, my particle system won't "bake to keyframes" as you have suggested.  So I am still looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: Well, as I commented on my answer at the other question, no my solution doesn't work for particles - that's why I didn't post it here but under a question about rigid bodies.